# Nginx reverse proxy returning 404 when server is down

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm reverse proxying all traffic for a subdomain to a local server.

Using the following directive works great when the proxied server is up.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8900;
}
```

When localhost:8900 is down, nginx returns a 404. Is there a way to return a 502 or equivalent?

Comment: Show full nginx config

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MiJMBcKB

Answer (score 1):

Turns out when I migrated my nginx.confs to a new server, the error page locations changed and nginx couldn't find the error page thus serving a 404.